# Failed the parent DAG if subdag got failed instead of try for retry

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

How to Failed the parent DAG if subdag got failed instead of try for retry in Airflow. I have DAG in one of task is itself is DAG to get the status of sub dag and accordingly Parent DAG should processed But in my case sub dag got failed in one of task but parent dag is still went to retry option. If Sub Dag got failed then parent dag should be failed.

I am new to Airflow. How to do that.

Comment: What version of Airflow are you using? Can you post a code example showing what Operators you are using to trigger/get status of the subdag?

Comment: I can't post the code here. It is permissible. I am using python operator

Comment: Using Managed Apache Airflow version 2.0.2